# Generated .NET Core 2.2 exe starts on a different port

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to generate an .exe for my .NET Core 2.2 app and start it on a certain port (let's say 5432). I added `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` to my .csproj to generate the exe and added a custom `applicationUrl` in my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": { ... },
        "MyApp": {
            ...
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5432"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `dotnet run` the app starts as expected on port 5432, but when I build the solution in VS 2017 and run the exe it always starts on 5000 and 5001. I know that I can add `--urls=""`, but I was wondering if there is a way to take the port from my `launchSettings.json`.

I am running the .exe from PowerShell, I only use Visual Studio to rebuild the solution.

Comment: Are you running the exe from the cmdline or from Visual Studio? If the latter, VS has some options in Project properties/Debug that might be overriding your settings

Comment: @ESG I am running the exe using Powershell, I will update the question appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `launchSettings.json` is only supposed to be used by Visual Studio, it is only for developing purpose, you shouldn't rely on it, when run in staging/production/non-developer machine.
In other words, it was not designed to use port from this file when you starting application from outside VS.

Answer (score 0):

In `Program.cs`, in your `CreateWebHostBuilder()` method, you can use

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseUrls(“http://[IP]:[Port]”);
```

This port will be used in both Debug & Release configurations.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, since this is the same as `--urls=""`

Comment: Well, `launchSettings.json` is a VS only resource. You could easily use a JSON file to store your own version of `applicationUrl`, read the value and pass it into `UseUrls()`.

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core. Kestrel is the webserver that's included by default in ASP.NET Core project templates. When you do `dotnet run` it correctly refers to `MyApp` settings in the `launchconfig.json`

I think when you use visual studio it is defaulting to IIS Express settings. If you change the default to not use IIS Express you'll be fine.

[image]

Comment: I updated my question, I am running the .exe from Powershell, not from VS

Comment: A little confused. how could a web app have an exe? I am adding comments assuming you meant a dll. Did you try dotnet cli? like below:
$ dotnet build -c Release -o ./app
$ dotnet run ./app/myapp.dll

Comment: If you target Windows specifically you can generate an .exe `dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Wickedlizerd works for me, thanks. I'm running .exe file, so I can't set the web url. So I just need to change a bit, since I'm using the .NET 7. I used this:

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls(new[] { "http://domainName:5005" });
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35503674)